# C memory leaks in program

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

I would need advice on where in the program I did not release the allocated memory. In my opinion, it is somewhere in the commented part, which in this form was to compile me.

Here, in some way, I work with memory and try to free it.

When writing `free(diagonaly);` in if(nr<=0 ) throws me an error.

This condition is fulfilled at the moment when diagonaly `diagonaly = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*diagonaly)*rDiagonaly)` is allocated, but no line is allocated.

```
int main (void)
{
    char **diagonaly;
    char **docasne;
    int rDiagonaly = 10;
    int cDiagonaly = -1;

    char *str = NULL;
    size_t  capacity = 0;
    int first = 1;
    int nr = 0;
    
    printf("Vypln:\n");
    while ( getline (&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1)
    {
        if(str[0] == '\n')
                break;
        //valid control
        if ( !validni(str, cDiagonaly) )
        {
            printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
                free (diagonaly[i]);
            free(diagonaly);
            free(str);
            return 0;
        }
        
        if (first)
        {
            cDiagonaly = strlen (str)+1;
            diagonaly = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*diagonaly)*rDiagonaly);
            first = 0;
        }   
        
        if (nr==rDiagonaly)
            {
                rDiagonaly *= 2; 
                docasne = (char**)realloc (diagonaly, rDiagonaly*sizeof(*diagonaly));
                diagonaly=docasne;
            }
        
        diagonaly[nr]=(char*) malloc (cDiagonaly*sizeof(**diagonaly));
        strcpy(diagonaly[nr],str);
        
        nr++;
        
    }

    if(nr<=0 )
    {
        printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
        free(str);
                //free (diagonaly[0]);
            //free(diagonaly);
            return 0;
        return 0;
    }   
    
    rDiagonaly = nr;
    char **maska;
    int rMaska = nr+1;
    int cMaska = cDiagonaly+1;
    str = NULL;
    capacity = 0;
    

    nr=0;
    
    maska=(char**)malloc (rMaska*sizeof(*maska));
    for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
        maska[i]=(char *) malloc (cMaska*sizeof(**maska));
    
    printf("Maska:\n");
    while ( getline (&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1)
    {
        
        if(nr == rMaska)
        {
            printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rDiagonaly; i++)
                free (diagonaly[i]);
            free(diagonaly);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
                free (maska[i]);
            free(maska);
            free(str);
            
            
            return 0;
        }
        //valid control
        if ( validniM(str, cMaska) )
        {
            strcpy(maska[nr],str);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < rDiagonaly; i++)
                free (diagonaly[i]);
            free(diagonaly);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
                free (maska[i]);
            free(maska);
            free(str);
            return 0;
        }
        nr++;
    }
    
    if (nr != rMaska)
    {
        printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < rDiagonaly; i++)
                free (diagonaly[i]);
            free(diagonaly);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
                free (maska[i]);
            free(maska);
            free(str);
        return 0;
    }   


    for (int i = 0; i < rDiagonaly; i++)
                free (diagonaly[i]);
            free(diagonaly);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
                free (maska[i]);
            free(maska);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: You should really provide a [mcve]. The missing functions could be the problem, but I didn't check. With VS I'd just check which allocation wasn't freed. Another suggestion is to wrap the diagonaly allocator and deallocator in two functions.

Comment: OK, let's take a look at it in VS, the other functions only check the loaded strings, there is no work with memory

Comment: Use Valgrind. It will tell you, where memory leaks occur.

Comment: I really don't get why you just don't edit the post and provide that [mcve]. It will improve your chances of getting an answer which will solve your problem!

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? For which input does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm pretty sure this answer will never be read, but anyway...*

The problem is that you didn't initialize `diagonaly`. So if you provide an empty line as your first line, it will be pointing to a random location in memory and `free()` will likely crash your program.

The solution is to remember to initialize your pointers:

```c
char **diagonaly = NULL;
```

Of course, you shouldn't be doing `free(diagonaly[0])`, because `nr` was `0`, meaning that dereferencing `diagonally` is wrong.